# Blackberry 10 not running on Mac

Tags: mobile-device-management

Connecting my Blackberry to my Mac I'm able to install the drivers that show up and install some software.

But other than that nothing is working.

No device is showing up in Finder.

No Blackberry application added to "Applications".

The only thing I see is the following in /Library/Application Support/Blackberry:

[image: Only files I see added]

The Device Manager doesn't appear to open anything.

Am I missing something.  This is a work BB so is it possible they locked down the ability for me to see in OS X?

Comment: The version of macOS you are using?  Do you see the device when you issue the command `sudo dmesg` in Terminal?

Comment: mac OS Sierra v10.12.6.... no I dont see it in sudo dmesg

Comment: If you are not seeing it show up as a recognized device, loading drivers will have no effect.  Can you confirm that it works with other devices?

Comment: Did you check OS compatibility on the BB site?